# Models inside a ViewModel have null property values when submitted using Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

ViewModel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public Organization.Event Evt { get; set; }
    public GuestContributor Gst { get; set; }
}
```

Through this ViewModel, I am displaying event data using `Evt` property which is working fine. And Gst property used to get data from a form on the same page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GuestApplyToEvent", "Event", FormMethod.Post))
{ <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Gst.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Gst.Name)
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Gst.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email Address" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Gst.Email)
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 ">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Gst.Mobile, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Mobile (WhatsApp Number)" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Gst.Mobile)
    </div>
 </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn dorne-btn" value="Apply" />

                                           }}
```

When sending this ViewModel to my View I am not assigning anything to Gst.

And this is the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GuestApplyToEvent(Models.GuestContributor eventViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("~/Views/Event/Index.cshtml", eventViewModel);

    return View("~/Views/Event/Index.cshtml", eventViewModel);
}
```

The problem is that all the properties in `eventViewModel` are null even after the data is entered.

Comment: Reason for -1 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Post method` is expecting a model of type `GuestContributor` but in your View it appears you are using model `EventViewModel`, try changing your `Post Method` to receive model type `EventViewModel`

Comment: that was my first guess. I tried that but still the same issue. In that scenario both `evt` and `gst` has null parameters.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva Are all the parameters `null` or just the ones which are not being bound in your form? Also, do those properties you are passing in the form have `public level` and have `set methods`?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva I take it that it is working now? Happy coding.

Comment: Your last comment made me remember that when I tested with `EventViewModel` as the input to the action, I never passed the values to the fields. My bad! Thanks :)

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva No problem. Glad I could help